# IE website picture load time takes forever

Tags: internet-explorer

This seems like such a simple question but for the life of me I can't figure out the problem...

I've developed a WordPress theme for a family member for their small business website.  She did not have much written content so the site is very picture heavy - http://www.ladybuglocks.com

I've tested this in multiple browsers and all of them seem to work great except for Internet Explorer.  Each time I go to a new page it takes FOREVER (well, in internet time at least) to load the pictures and it's very frustrating.  It gets stuck where at the bottom it says "10 items remaining", and it can take 5-10 seconds for the pictures to appear.

I've developed more than a handful websites, many with photo galleries, and I've never seen this problem before.

If any of you can visit the site, attempt to recreate the problem and give me pointers with how to fix it, it will be so very appreciated!  My cousin wants to start advertising but doesn't feel comfortable doing this with the website feeling unresponsive.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce this. The head banner and 3 main content pictures take at least 1-2 seconds longer to load in IE 8 (and thereafter as well, as long as the cache is cleared) than they do in Chrome. Can I suggest troubleshooting by loading *just* one of the slow-loading images from your web server into IE? It's possible IE is having trouble with .PNGs...

Comment: well if you mean addressing the url of the jpg to load just the picture, i did that and it didn't seem to be that slow or anything that would cause such long delays.  I always use PNGs for a lot of background images and never had any problems before.  This surely is frustrating, it seems like the answer should be something more obvious

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I just did the same thing, and it seems fine. I've heard of problems in IE with transparent PNGs, but that's usually been older versions than 8, and the other pictures are JPGs anyway. Although, with further testing, it seems like the entire site is slow and unresponsive feeling with IE (compared to Chrome). As far as an obvious answer, I don't know either.

Comment: Something tells me it has something to do with WordPress because most of my other sites that have photo galleries are pure HTML sites and none of them have had problems.  But I don't understand how WP could possibly slow it down THAT much, and only for IE.

Comment: hmmmm, it does seem to load a bit faster if I completely remove Google font API and all javascript/jquery... but that is kind of a big part of the site design.  I just find it interesting that I've used several of these resources to add to a design before and never encountered this issue until now.

Answer (score 0):

Well they're optimised and decent sizes... is your bandwidth suffering intermittently? I see they're served from Wordpress, do they use a CDN (content distribution network) in some strange way?

My advice is to use Google Chrome Web Dev tools, turn on 'resource tracking' in the console and watch where your bottlenecks occur. You can do something similar with YSlow addon for Firefox.

Nothing else looks amiss to me, perhaps there's a resource that isn't available but you're trying to load it?

Edit: Ok actually yeah the Wordpress page is linking to Google AJAX API and stuff like that, I experience horrible slowness with Google's CDN, maybe you're in a remote part of the world like me?

Comment: The homepage pictures are simply hardcoded into the home.php template and reside in the theme's image directory.  The rest of the product pictures were uploaded directly to the posts via the wordpress uploader.

I thought it might have been image sizes but you did notice that I cut them down as much as I could without losing too much quality... however I only did this with the homepage pictures.  My cousin controls the wordpress uploads so I can't really optimize those for her (she isn't very computer savvy).

Comment: Mmm, it zapped down to me, I didn't notice any slowness whatsoever ... heh, though stackoverflow is crawling for me :P

Comment: Nope, I'm in the US, and never had any troubles with Google's CDN!!  Maybe my computer is just messed up... I appreciate a few people testing out, though, I'll have to do the same on a couple different computers myself

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm not seeing anything egregiously slow in IE8 here (performance is pretty close to being on par with Chrome), and I have a *horrible* internet connection.

Comment: See thats what I don't get.  It's fast on mine after I visit the page and it's in my cache.  But if I clear my internet history the problem reoccurs.  And my internet connection is nothing shabby!  I just used Google Web Developer tools and the resource tracking time was 800ms, seems pretty fast to me but for some reason the dang pictures take so long to appear.

Comment: I doubt it, I edited most of these in photoshop and exported them using the 'save for web and devices' tool.... I also just tested on http://tools.pingdom.com - it consistently finishes around 2.5 seconds.

Comment: So, it's having probs with the request, if is not a prob when is in cache...Anyway, here is a problem even while loaded in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Does not happen in Firefox 3.x

It does in Internet Explorer 7/8.

Problem seem to live in the js you are using. I doubt it'd be in jquery defaults, is mostly common to be in your custom js. You are asking for some fx, or some petition that gets IEs into trouble. (sorry, busy to dig much the code right now)

If it has worked well in other sites and you tested in IE browsers, just think of what you have done differently, or added, even if sounds crazy, as it will be faster to spot the problem doing so.

Comment: Hmm... this sounds logical however I took out the two pieces of custom javascript and I still encountered the slow loading issues.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just had a look at the code, now... Seems you are using a php for loading the thumbnails. Might be it, wether is a coding problem in the php, only giving problems to IEs, or that the server is having probs with its mysql or php: ...uglocks.com/wp-content/themes/ladybug/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.ladybuglocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/IMG_1343.jpg&w=214&h=142&zc=1

Comment: There are several parameters there: Maybe try not adding them in a single page that has enough thumbs, and see what happens in IEs. I found the php you are using, and for example, that zc parameter means zoom crop. Maybe some of that is asking too much for IE. In general though, the site is not fluid in performance in IE, chunks a lot. In firefox it works great instead. Is not your fault...

Comment: I mean that you can actually delete from the urls parameters, so to see if hunt what is causing it all. The timthumb code:
http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php

Comment: I'd try removing witdth, height and zc parameters, to test. Also seems ppl say that script is slow in ie, for several persons. It can be also that it adds some problem with teh transparency code. Shots in the dark, usual issues with IE are related to that in some cases.

Comment: I will go ahead and try that but for some reason I doubt that's the problem.  Reason being that I don't use the timthumb script on the homepage at all and it still loads in chunks like you said... I'm beyond frustrated, i don't understand what else this could be!!